# Evento (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" No funciona en Angular Material

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

Estoy trabajando unos formularios con Angular Material, pero su evento (change) no me funciona:

```
<mat-form-field class="form-group col-md-6">
  <mat-label>Seleccione Servicios</mat-label>
  <mat-select name="servicios" [(ngModel)]="selectServicio.id"  (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let servicio of servicios" value= {{servicio.id}}>
      {{servicio.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Sin embargo lo he probado sin los estilos de Angular Material y funciona:

```
    <select name="servicios" [(ngModel)]="selectServicio.id"  (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let servicio of servicios" value= {{servicio.id}}>
        {{servicio.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Esto lo estoy haciendo para una lista dependiente, si alguien tiene una mejor idea por favor le agradecería

Answer (score 3):

Ya encontré en la documentacion la soulucion hice el cambio por:

```
(valueChange)="onSelect($event)
```

https://material.angular.io/components/select/api